# Any plans for a non backwords compatible WP release?

Tags: wordpress-version

Imagine all the old_functions_that_do_the_same_thing_as_new_functions() being ripped out. Think of the consistency and improved work flow while working with different themes and plugins.

Is there already a branch like this or is there something in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no such plans. WordPress intentionally maintains backward compatibility.